# IIS crash occurs often.. ASP.net app on IIS 6 Win 2003

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have this ASP.net app running on IIS 6 on win 2003.
I get this issue of iis crash very often in the range of every few minutes..

The application is often restarted and loses all the session information.

Event viewer shows below information:

EventType clr20r3, P1 w3wp.exe, P2 6.0.3790.3959, P3 45d6968e, P4 app_code.soku_afh, P5 0.0.0.0, P6 4a12f739, P7 2f6, P8 30, P9 exception, P10 NIL.

Any pointers on how to go about solving it..

Comment: this is chendur Hope you remember me? Is it possible to integrate gwt with asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 1):

Similar questions that may be of help:

- [w3wp.exe is crashing frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603239/w3wp-exe-is-crashing-frequently)
- [IIS 6.0 Application Pool Crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476473/iis-6-0-application-pool-crash)
- [IIS Hand Troubleshooting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643734/iis-hang-troubleshooting)
- [Getting IIS Worker Process Crash Dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435/getting-iis-worker-process-crash-dumps)

Answer (score 0):

try to use your own machine key on web.config, it could solve the problem

Comment: asp.net encrypts or decrypts the viewstate data with a machine key which placed on general configuration. i dont know why but it crashes the web site if your web site placed on a web farm, or your server has more than one web application. so you can customize the machine key on the web site's web.config file.. there is a tool here : http://aspnetresources.com/tools/keycreator.aspx create your own key and put it to web.config file